# Why everyone can mute anyone even after there is a moderator?

Tags: reactjs, jitsi

I am creating a video meet interface in react using `'@jitsi/react-sdk'`.When a room is created then even after there is a moderator everyone is able to mute anyone why is it happening.
Here is the code:

```
import { JitsiMeeting } from '@jitsi/react-sdk';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const apiRef = useRef();
  const [logItems, updateLog] = useState([]);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
  const [knockingParticipants, updateKnockingParticipants] = useState([]);
  const addParticipants = payload => {
    setUsers(items => [...items, payload]);
  }
  const removeParticipants = payload => {
    setUsers(participants => participants.filter(item => item.id !== payload.id));
  }

  const printEventOutput = payload => {
    updateLog(items => [...items, JSON.stringify(payload)]);
  };

  const handleAudioStatusChange = (payload, feature) => {
    if (payload.muted) {
      updateLog(items => [...items, `${feature} off`])
    } else {
      updateLog(items => [...items, `${feature} on`])
    }
  };

  const handleChatUpdates = payload => {
    if (payload.isOpen || !payload.unreadCount) {
      return;
    }
    apiRef.current.executeCommand('toggleChat');
    updateLog(items => [...items, `you have ${payload.unreadCount} unread messages`])
  };

  const handleKnockingParticipant = payload => {
    updateLog(items => [...items, JSON.stringify(payload)]);
    updateKnockingParticipants(participants => [...participants, payload?.participant])
  };

  const handleJitsiIFrameRef1 = iframeRef => {
    iframeRef.style.border = '10px solid #3d3d3d';
    iframeRef.style.background = '#3d3d3d';
    iframeRef.style.height = '400px';
  };


  const handleApiReady = apiObj => {
    apiRef.current = apiObj;
    apiRef.current.on('knockingParticipant', handleKnockingParticipant);
    apiRef.current.on('audioMuteStatusChanged', payload => handleAudioStatusChange(payload, 'audio'));
    apiRef.current.on('videoMuteStatusChanged', payload => handleAudioStatusChange(payload, 'video'));
    apiRef.current.on('raiseHandUpdated', printEventOutput);
    apiRef.current.on('titleViewChanged', printEventOutput);
    apiRef.current.on('chatUpdated', handleChatUpdates);
    apiRef.current.on('knockingParticipant', handleKnockingParticipant);
    apiRef.current.on('participantJoined', addParticipants);
    apiRef.current.on('participantKickedOut', removeParticipants);
    apiRef.current.on('participantLeft', removeParticipants);
  };

  const handleReadyToClose = () => {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line no-alert */
    alert('Ready to close...');
  };

  const generateRoomName = () => `JitsiMeetRoomNo${Math.random() * 100}-${Date.now()}`;

  const renderSpinner = () => (
    <div style={{
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }}>
      Loading..
    </div>
  );


  return (
    <>
      <h1 style={{
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        textAlign: 'center'
      }}>
        JitsiMeeting App
      </h1>
      <JitsiMeeting
        roomName={generateRoomName()}
        spinner={renderSpinner}
        configOverwrite={{
          startWithAudioMuted: true,
          startWithVideoMuted: true,
        }}
        config={{
          hideConferenceSubject: false
        }}
        onApiReady={externalApi => handleApiReady(externalApi)}
        onReadyToClose={handleReadyToClose}
        getIFrameRef={handleJitsiIFrameRef1} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong and roundabout to get the feature implemented where only moderator can mute the mic and camera of other participants.